403 Forbidden error, Ubuntu 24.04 LTS + Backuppc 4
After doing a fresh Ubuntu install and configuring webmin proceeded to install BackupPC 4 on the machine as requested.  Understand that this program is old but is what I've been asked to do.
When trying to access http://locahost/backuppc from the server the page shows up correctly, but when I try to connect to http://ipaddress/backuppc from any other workstation I get a 403 Forbidden error.
Forbidden  
You don't have permission to access this resource.  
Apache/2.4.58 (Ubuntu) Server at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx Port 80  

Results of ls /etc/apache2 :
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 7178 
Dec 26 10:50 apache2.conf drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 
Dec 24 10:38 conf-available drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 
Dec 24 10:38 conf-enabled -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1782 
Mar 18 2024 envvars -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 31063 
Mar 18 2024 magic drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 12288 
Dec 24 10:37 mods-available drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 
Dec 24 10:38 mods-enabled -

I have been looking around for hours, and I can't find anything that actually works. Do you have any ideas?

I am guessing the permissions on the Apache service folder isn't setup correctly. Can you ping that ip from other workstation?

Pings are successful, the firewall is disabled, Apache is listening to port 80.

So what permissions exist on the apache folder, can we see them?

/etc/apache2
drwxr-xr-x   8 root                 root                  4096 Dec 26 10:50 apache2

Contents of /etc/apache2
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  7178 Dec 26 10:50 apache2.conf
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Dec 24 10:38 conf-available
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Dec 24 10:38 conf-enabled
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  1782 Mar 18  2024 envvars
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 31063 Mar 18  2024 magic
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 12288 Dec 24 10:37 mods-available
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Dec 24 10:38 mods-enabled
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   274 Mar 18  2024 ports.conf
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Dec 24 10:37 sites-available
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root  4096 Dec 24 10:37 sites-enabled

Do ls -l /var/www/html let's see the permissions

Result of ls -l on /var/www
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Dec 24 10:37 html
Result of ls -l on /var/www/html
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10671 Dec 24 10:37 index.html

Run this command sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html to modify the user and group ownership, then run sudo find /var/www/html -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \; sudo find /var/www/html -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;. Please note they are two separate commands in the second set. After this restart the service and try again

Executed the commands as follows:
sudo find /var/www/html -type f -exec chmod 644 {} ;
sudo find /var/www/html -type d -exec chmod 755 {} ;
sudo find /var/www/html -type f -exec chmod 644 {} ;
Result:
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 10671 Dec 24 10:37 index.html
sudo systemctl restart apache2
Still doesn't work, get the 403 Forbidden.

Did you run this sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html?

Believe I did but just to make sure did it again.
before: -rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 10671 Dec 24 10:37 index.html
command: sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html
Result: -rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data 10671 Dec 24 10:37 index.html
As you can see nothing changed.

One thing to notice is that backuppc is not in /var/www/html, have no idea how it gets called when requesting "http://ipaddress or hostname/backuppc".
